# Issue running yarn watch with webpack

Tags: webpack, yarnpkg

I am working on a project and using webpack for the first time. I ran into an issue running `yarn watch`. Here is my code in webpage.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

// include the js minification plugin
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

// include the css extraction and minification plugins
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/js/site.js', './src/scss/style.scss'],
  output: {
    filename: './dist/js/site.min.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname)
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // perform js babelization on all .js files
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
          presets: ['babel-preset-env']
          }
        }
      },
      // compile all .scss files to plain old css
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // extract css into dedicated file
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: './dist/css/style.min.css',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname)
    })
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      // enable the js minification plugin
      new UglifyJSPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true
      }),
      // enable the css minification plugin
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  }
};
```

In running this I get a couple of errors. The first says:

> Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found

and then another one comes up that says:

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'FOLDER_NAME_HERE' error Command failed with exit code 2.

Here is my package.json file as well:

```
{
  "name": "project name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "project description",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode development",
    "dist": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack --watch --mode development"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "imagemin-cli": "^3.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

I did a little searching and found some stuff on Github regarding this, but no real solutions. I have a '/src' folder so it makes no sense for an error to say it can't resolve './src' unless that file path is incorrect (I've tried all sort of other possibilities just to test it, what I have now is what it was originally). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"watch": "webpack --watch --mode development --config ./path/to/my/webpack/config"`

You didn't say which config is to look for... you have to say it